# yii multiple upload save paths in database does not work

Tags: php, yii

Im pretty new to Yii, and just added a function that an admin can upload multiple files. However, the model is saving the images that are uploaded to the appropriate folder, but not saving the paths/names of the images into the database.

How can i do this?

database look like:

id | naam | beschrijving | prijs | actieprijs | categorie | subcategorie | images | toegevoegd | aangepast | aangepast_door

Controller:

```
$model=$this->loadModel($id);
        $dir = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.images.producten');
        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Producten']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Producten'];

            $images = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('images');

            // proceed if the images have been set
            if (isset($images) && count($images) > 0) {

                // go through each uploaded image
                foreach ($images as $image => $pic) {
                    $fn = str_replace(" ", "-", $pic->name);
                    if ($pic->saveAs($dir.'/'.$fn)) {
                        // add it to the main model now
                        $img_add = new Producten();
                        $img_add->images = $fn; //it might be $img_add->name for you, filename is just what I chose to call it in my model

                        $img_add->save(); // DONE
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                // handle the errors here, if you want
            }
                // save the rest of your information from the form
            if ($model->save()) {
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
            }
            /*
            $model->images=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'images');
            $nf = str_replace(" ", "+", $model->images);

            if($model->save()){
                $model->images->saveAs($dir.'/'.$nf);
                $model->images = $nf;
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
            }
            */
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
```

Please help!!

Comment: Does a new record gets inserted into the appropriate table? If yes, what is the value of the images field? Also, can you show us the scheme of the Producten model?

Comment: No it does not save it into database at all, scheme is in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, it kept overwriting the image in the database, so if i uploaded 5 photo's, only the last photo would be in the database. It did however save them all 5 to the correct path. Now i made this, and it seems to work:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Producten;
        $dir = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.images.producten');

        if(isset($_POST['Producten']))
        {
            $old_images = explode(',',strtoupper($model->images));

            $model->attributes=$_POST['Producten'];

            $images = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('images');

            if (isset($images) && count($images) > 0) {

                $img_add = new Producten();

                foreach ($images as $image => $pic) {
                    $fn = str_replace(" ", "-", strtoupper($pic->name));
                    if ($pic->saveAs($dir.'/'.$fn)) {

                    if(!in_array($fn, $old_images)){
                        $model->images .= $fn.",";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $model->toegevoegd=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now'));
        $model->aangepast=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now'));
        $model->aangepast_door=Yii::app()->user->id;

        if ($model->save()) {
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you code is OK. Here I suggest you to add error reporting to see if there exist any error. Simply can try below codes

```
$img_add->images = $fn;                        
if(!$img_add->save()){
   var_dump($img_add->getErrors());
}
```

No need to create the object of `Producten` model several times in `foreach()`. You can place `$img_add = new Producten();` before `foreach()`. Also can use `unset($img_add->images)` before assigning 
`$img_add->images = $fn;` if required.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it just update the same record and overwrite the images field with the last one?